# How to pipe & convert the first field from decimal to hex

Tags: debian, networking, pipe, conversion, mac-address

I've got the following onscreen output

```
170.170.170.0.156.96 24
```

that I would like to pipe & convert to the following format

```
b8:27:eb:ef:3b:4a 24
```

in essence it is a decimal to hex conversion of the first field whereby the dots are replace by colons. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

```
$ cat input
170.170.170.0.156.96 24
$ perl -lane '$F[0] =~ s/(\d+)/sprintf "%02x",$1/eg; $F[0] =~ tr/./:/; print "@F"' < input
aa:aa:aa:00:9c:60 24
$
```

Loop over standard input not printing with a split into `@F`, mangle the first column (`$F[0]`) replacing all digit runs with their hex equivalent plus the . to : `tr`anslation. Print the new values contained in `@F`.

Comment: Works like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

**`Python`** approaches:

-- using `re` module:

```
python -c 'import sys,re;
print(re.sub(r"\d+(?!$)", lambda m: "{:x}".format(int(m.group())), 
sys.stdin.read().strip()))' <inputfile
```

---

-- using `split()` + `map()` + `join()` chain:

```
python -c 'import sys; parts=sys.stdin.read().strip().split(); 
print(".".join(map(lambda n: "{:x}".format(int(n)), parts[0].split("."))) 
 + " " + parts[1])' <inputfile
```

---

The output (for both approaches):

```
aa.aa.aa.0.9c.60 24
```

Comment: Just curious,  why you chose to use `re` module instead of splitting into lists ?

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy, because "split -> slicing -> map with converting to hex -> join" approach would be a bit "longer" and less readable. See my update

Answer (score 1):

Using `awk` and treating  the dots as record separators:

```
echo '170.170.170.0.156.96 24' |
awk -v RS='.' '{ s = (s ? s ":" : "" ) sprintf("%02x", $0) } END { print s }'
```

Here, the resulting string `s` is built up from converting the decimal integers to hexadecimal using `sprintf()`. At the end of input, the result is printed.

Note that the trailing `24` is discarded in the decimal to hexadecimal conversion, so no explicit handling of it is required.

The result of the above pipeline is the string `aa:aa:aa:00:9c:60`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution with `awk`:

```
$ awk -F. \
 '{for(i=1; i<6; i++){printf "%02x:", $i}\
 {  printf "%02x ", $6 }printf substr($6, length($6)-1, length($6))"\n"}' inputfile
```

It loops over the first 5 fields separated by `.`, prints the hex conversion with `:`, and then 6th one without `:`. Then separates `24` from the 6th field by printing last two characters.

Answer (score 0):

A tricky awk:

```
$ cat file1
170.170.170.0.156.96 24
170.170.170.0.156.96 28

$ awk '{printf "%x%s",$0,RT=="."?":":RT}' RS="[. ]|\n" file1
aa:aa:aa:0:9c:60 18
aa:aa:aa:0:9c:60 1c
```

Comment: didn't work for me, produced different output from above:

aaaaaa09c6018aaaaaa09c601c

Comment: @R4C3R Give a try to the updated-shorter-code. In my gawk works fine. Maybe your awk is not gnu awk (i. mac or bsd).

Answer (score 0):

Another `awk` solution

```
$ awk -F. <inputfile \
'{for(i=1;i<7;i++){printf"%02x%c",$i,i<6?":":" "};print gensub(/.* /,"",$6)}'
```

Or in simplest form

```
$ awk -F. <inputfile \
'{printf"%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x %s",$1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,gensub(/^.* /,"",$6)}'
```

Shell/awk combo.  Relies on how shell `printf` happily keeps using same pattern for multiple arguments.

```
$ echo $A
170.170.170.0.156.96 24
$ printf "%02x:" ${A//./ }|awk -F'....$' -vc="${A#* }" '{print $1,c}'
aa:aa:aa:00:9c:60 24
$
```

Answer (score 0):

For processing the IP address portion, we can take advantage of `IFS` and word-splitting in subshell (hence unquoted `$var`) and `printf`'s ability to process variable-length arguments to fit into format string.

```
$ ( IFS='.';var='170.170.170.0.156.96';new=$(printf '%02x:' $var); echo ${new:0:${#new}-1} )
aa:aa:aa:00:9c:60
```

Also worth noting that  `${new:0:${#new}-1}` is used to trim off last `:` character blindly added by `printf`.

Considering that `170.170.170.0.156.96 24` may be coming as one single string of input on `stdin`, we could read both of them into variables and process separately:

```
$ echo "170.170.170.0.156.96 24" | while read ip num ;  do
> hex=$( IFS='.';new=$(printf '%02x:' $ip); echo ${new:0:${#new}-1} );  
> printf '%s %d\n' "$hex" "$num"; done
aa:aa:aa:00:9c:60 24
```

If you also need to make use of the output later in the script, consider writing the resulting value to  named pipe, continue working within same subshell, or using process substitution. See [this](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

With sed (GNU sed) 4.4

```
echo '170.170.170.0.156.96 24' | 
sed 'h;s/ .*//;s/\./ /g;s/^/printf "%02x:" /e;x;s/[^ ]* //;x;G;s/:\n/ /'
```